# Prove that this space is contractible

Tags: general-topology

Consider the space $X/\sim=((-1,1)\times \{0,1\})/\sim$ where $(x,0) \sim (x,1)$ for $x\leq0.$ Prove that $X/\sim$ is contractible.

I suppose we can contract $X/\sim$ to the point $[(0,0)] = [(0,1)]$. I have defined the following map

$$H: X \times [0,1] \to X \\ H(x,y,t)=((1-t)x, y)$$

So then  $H$ is continuous, $H(x,y,0) = (x,y)$ and $H(x,y,1) = (0,y)$. Going over to the quotient space $(0,y)$ is the same point whether $y=1$ or $y=0$.

Does this suffice to prove that $X/\sim$ is contractible?

Comment: The basic idea is fine, but you really do need a map $h$ from $(X/\!\!\sim)\times[0,1]$ to $X/\!\!\sim$, so you need to explain why there must be a continuous $h$ with the property that $h([\langle x,y\rangle],t)=H(x,y,t)$ for all relevant $x,y,t$.